# When I built Unity video game with Webgl it gives me an error

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, webgl, replit

I have recently Used Unity to create this simple game:
[image: The game]

And I built it with WebGl:
[image: Webgl]
but sadly it gives me this error message: "Unable to parse Build/Game.framework.js.br! This can happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: br" present. Check browser Console and Devtools Network tab to debug."

I NEED TO FIGURE OUT THE SOLUTION TO THIS BUG ASAP, thanks, Jake.

SideNote the website for this game is here: https://aliceblueemptysandbox.sweetmango88.repl.co/

Comment: It looks like Replit doesn't serve the pages with the requisite `Content-Encoding` header. You could enable decompression fallback to work around this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html

Comment: @Smitop I have enabled decompression fallback and it now gives me the error "Failed to download file Build/Game.framework.js.unityweb. Loading web pages via a file:// URL without a web server is not supported by this browser. Please use a local development web server to host Unity content, or use the Unity Build and Run option." Edit: It works now! thank you :D

Comment: ...then run a local web server or use the Unity Build and Run option? (if you upload the modified version to Replit it would also work)